# How to prove/disprove that $\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^k \left(H_{k-1}+\log (k)+\gamma \right)}{k}= 0$

Tags: harmonic-numbers, euler-sums

Playing around with the harmonic number $H(n) = 1+ \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + ... + \frac{1}{n}$ and its asymptotic approximation

$$H(n\to\infty) \simeq \gamma + \log(n) +\frac{1}{2n} -\frac{1}{12 n^2} + ...$$

I started with first order comparisions studying these sums

$$s_H = \sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^k H_{k-1}}{k}$$
$$s_L= \sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^k (\log (k)+\gamma )}{k}$$

Notice the shift in the argument of $H(k)$.

Mathematica tells me that

$$s_H = \frac{1}{2}\log ^2(2)$$
$$s_L = - \frac{1}{2}\log ^2(2)$$

Normally we would expect that the sum using $H$ should be comparable to that using an approximation of $H$. But this expectation is not justified at all here.

Hence we are "naturally" led to ask for this sum

$$s_{HL} = \sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^k \left(H_{k-1}+\left(\log (k)+\gamma \right)\right)}{k}$$

Here Mathematica finds that

$$s_{HL} = 0\tag{*}$$

I wouldn't have guessed that from looking at the summands.

Hence an independent proof of $(*)$ would be desirable.

Remark: this problem is related to [A closed form of the family of series $\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{\left(H_k\right){}^m-(\log (k)+\gamma )^m}{k}$ for $m\ge 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2582497/a-closed-form-of-the-family-of-series-sum-k-1-infty-frac-lefth-k-rig)

Comment: you are not rearranging the order of summation of the terms, you are just adding two convergent series. To see this you can use the definition of the values of the series as a limit of sums

Comment: @ masacroso you are right. Thank you. I have rephrased the question.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just compute the two sums directly? Isn't this itself the obvious approach to tackling the series?

Comment: @ Simply Beautiful Art: That is exactly what I did in the first place (see my OP). But I didn't expect that the sum using the harmonic number is exactly the negative of the sum which uses the approximation of $H_n$. Here some delicate cancellation takes place.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
s_H&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^kH_{k-1}}{k}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^kH_{k}}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k^2}\\
&=\frac12\ln^2(2)+\operatorname{Li}_2(-1)-\operatorname{Li}_2(-1)\\
&=\frac12\ln^22
\end{align}
where we used the generating function $\ \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^k H_k}{k}=\frac12\ln^2(1-x)+\operatorname{Li}_2(x)$

.

---

From [this solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3311884) , we proved $\ \int_0^\infty \ln x\ e^{-kx}\ dx=-\frac{\ln k+\gamma}{k}$ 
, so we can write

\begin{align}
s_L&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k(\ln k+\gamma)}{k}\\
&=-\int_0^\infty\ln x\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-e^{-x})^k\ dx\\
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-x}\ln x}{1+e^{-x}}\ dx
\end{align}

which I think manageable to prove it $-\frac12\ln^22$

Comment: For the last integral is enough to consider:
$$I(s)=\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x+1}dx=\eta(s)\Gamma(s)$$
$$\Rightarrow I'(s)=\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{s-1}\ln x}{e^x+1}dx=\frac{d}{ds}\left(\eta(s)\Gamma(s)\right)$$
And the result: $-\frac12 \ln^2 2$ follows by plugging $s=1$ and using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function#Derivatives.

Comment: and solution is complete :)

Comment: But now that I think of it, we don't need the integral representation, since $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k \ln k}{k}$ is actually $\eta'(1)$. Well both ways ends to the same result.

Comment: That's a way to go too.

Comment: @ Ali Shather Elegant and efficient, as always. May I draw your attention to my older question, on which you are herewith invited to test your capabilities? (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2582497/a-closed-form-of-the-family-of-series-sum-k-1-infty-frac-lefth-k-rig)

Comment: @Dr. Wolfgang Hintze thank you for your kind words, it means a lot coming from an experienced person like you.  That problem is really interesting I will try it and see what I get.