# How to evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{kn}^2-[\gamma+\ln(kn)]^2}{n}?$

Tags: sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers, euler-mascheroni-constant

From this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/866382/a-closed-form-of-the-series-sum-n-1-infty-frach-n2-gamma-ln-n2?rq=1) [@Olivier Oloa](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/118798/olivier-oloa) gives the closed form for this sum $(1)$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n^2-(\gamma+\ln n)^2}{n}=\frac{5}{3}\zeta(3)-\frac{2}{3}\gamma^3-2\gamma\gamma_1-\gamma_2\tag1$$

I was trying to generalises $(2)$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{kn}^2-[\gamma+\ln(kn)]^2}{n}=F(k)\tag2$$
where $k\ge1$

but I couldn't only got so far finding out the closed form for $k=2$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{2n}^2-[\gamma+\ln(2n)]^2}{n}=\frac{11}{12}\zeta(3)-\frac{2}{3}\gamma^3-2\gamma\gamma_1-\gamma_2+\eta(1)[\eta(2)-\gamma^2-2\gamma_1]\tag3$$

where [$\eta(k)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function) is the Dirichlet eta function

**Does anyone knows how to find the closed form for $(2)$?**

Comment: Why not just write $\eta(1)=\ln{(2)}$ and $\eta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{12}$